# Playing a sound in Flex (Flash) and hearing nothing

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, audio

Rats!

I'm doing a [by-the-book](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Working_with_Sound_07.html) sound playback in Flex and I can't hear it.

I tried this:

```
var snd : Sound = new Sound();
snd.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e : Event) : void
{
    snd.play();
});
snd.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, function(e : IOErrorEvent) : void
{
    Log.format("Playing gong sound failed...\n{0}", e.toString());
});
snd.load(new URLRequest("http://localhost:8000/gong.wav"));
```

And I tried the simpler:

```
var snd : Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("http://localhost:8000/gong.wav"));
snd.play();
```

But I hear nothing. Launching the same mp3 file in vlc plays it fine. So yes, my speakers are turned on. :)

It's not the loading. I can see it's actually loading those 40k bytes fine, and if I give the wrong URL I **do** get an IOError. It's as if it's playing but nothing can be heard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From "[Working with Sound](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Working_with_Sound_07.html)" in the flex documentation:

> Although there are various sound file formats used to encode digital
>   audio, ActionScript 3.0, Flash Player and AIR support sound files that
>   are stored in the mp3 format. They cannot directly load or play sound
>   files in other formats like WAV or AIFF.

Sure you're playing an mp3?  Your URL says ".wav"...

Comment: +1 was typing the exact same thing. Documentation for [Sound](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6)